# A truly rigorous textbook

Tags: education

Does there exist a mathematical text that references a formal computer verified proof for every theorem it presents? I'm imagining a digital textbook that gives the higher level concepts in typical prose but also provides a means to examine each logical step in as much detail as desired. If not, is such a thing feasible or likely to be attempted?

Comment: I imagine the answer is "no", as the level of detail of a computer-verified proof would have little to no practical value to a reader, and would likely be much harder to get through than a normal textbook. That being said, https://www.isa-afp.org/ is a database of computer-verified proofs that may be useful.

Comment: @NMister I was kind of imagining something where the prose follows the formal proof at a high level and provides links to increasing detail that the reader can follow if a certain step needs clarification. They wouldn't have to read it at the finest detail, but it would be easily accessible if needed.

Comment: The demand for formality strikes me as perhaps a more severe restriction than you would envision, but the book that comes to my mind is [Homotopy Type Theory -- Univalent Foundations for Mathematics](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/).  It is available in printed form and in PDF downloads.

Answer (score 3):

Not a textbook but a blog article by Timothy Gowers discussing the ability for computers to write proofs to problems at the level of analysis 1. Here he says

*"a few years ago I teamed up with a colleague of mine, Mohan Ganesalingam, to write a computer program to solve easy problems.*"
and then he goes on to discuss the process

Here's the link  https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/how-to-work-out-proofs-in-analysis-i/